# Why won't my Collection View Cells display in the iPhone Simulator?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, ios-simulator, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to programmatically create a Collection View with six cells.  The iPhone Simulator in Xcode 8 told me that my build was successful. **There is still an error though.**

Any help spotting the bug or bugs that are causing my cells not to display in the Simulator is greatly appreciated.  (I put the Collection View directly into the IB from the Object Library.  Also, I want each cell to occupy the entire size of the Collection View, hence `displayedCellDimensions`, because the user will segue between cells when a forward or backward button is tapped.)  Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class FluidIntakeMainMenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {



//MARK: - Collection View Properties
@IBOutlet weak var ibCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var cellArray:[customCollectionViewCell] = Array(repeating: customCollectionViewCell(), count: 6)

let displayedCellDimensions = CGSize(width: 343, height: 248)



//MARK: - Xcode-generated Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    ibCollectionView.dataSource = self
    ibCollectionView.delegate = self


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: - Collection View Methods
//Place cells in collection view and change the cell size
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if collectionView.visibleCells.isEmpty {
        for cell in 0...cellArray.count {
            collectionView.addSubview(cellArray[cell])
            return CGSize(width: 343, height: 248)
        }
    }
    return CGSize(width: 343, height: 248)
}

//Register a new cell
func registerCell(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) {
    for _ in 0...cellArray.count {
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return cellArray.count


}
...}
```

Comment: read this https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started you didn't setup your UICollectionView

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko - The tutorial starts with a whole Collection View Controller scene.  Since I want to include other things in this scene, does that mean that I would need to put my Collection View Controller in a Container View?

Comment: tutorial shows you how to setup and use UICollectionView

Comment: return 1 in this function func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad() Try:

```
viewDidLoad() {
ibCollectionView.dataSource = self
ibCollectionView.delegate = self
}
```

Add this to the top of your class:

```
class FluidIntakeMainMenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```

You must use these functions in your ViewController class:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {}
```

Comment: That gives an error message that says the name of my class does not conform to the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol.  The delegate one seems to be working though.

Comment: Are you returning an Int in the numberOfItemsInSection... Can you update your code.. @ProgrammingEnthusiast

Comment: Okay I edited the code, and I also realized that I think some functions may be duplicates of each other.  Also, do I need to have the UICollectionView inside a Collection View Controller in a Container View (which is inside the main View Controller?

Comment: No you can have it in a view controller.. does not need to be in UICollectionViewcontroller

Comment: I am playing with the code: I did have a duplicate function, and I think I'm close to getting the code for the `numberOfItemsInSection` function.  Will update code with results.

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast ok I updated your code above you need to return an Int in the numberOfSections function...

Comment: If this helped, don't forget to mark this answer as correct!

Comment: Unfortunately, it made a successful build but now I am receiving a fatal error that stops the code from running.  Is this the code for the `class` or does it have something to do with the fact that the View Controller happens to be a Root View Controller for navigation that I have in the app?  Thank you for all your help though; once the code works, I will mark it as correct!

Comment: I did; I ran it again, and the specific error message highlights `ibCollectionView.dataSource = self` in red and displays, next to the code, "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"  Is it an executable bad instruction; what does it mean and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you have a custom class for your cell? @ProgrammingEnthusiast

Comment: No.  The cells for the collection view are the ones that are in the cellArray variable.

Comment: do I need  a separate class? do I need to put one cell into the Collection View IB and then put it into the code and create five identical cells to it?

Comment: I personally would make a separate class for the cells... no the cells will all be the same if you make them in IB, no need to create five different ones..

Comment: Okay thank you.  Do you know how I can get enough reputation to message you once I make the custom cell class if I have any questions at that point?

Comment: Just keep up the good work, and keep coding and asking great questions! @ProgrammingEnthusiast

Comment: I know this is a bit after the fact, but I created my custom cell class, and it's still giving me the same error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" The code above is all updated and everything.  Do you know what this means? Should I just post a new question?

Comment: No.  I've heard of it though.  Do I need an account?