# Error message when setting UICollectionView data source and delegate with custom class

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, ios-simulator, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating a sort of manual slideshow (i.e., the pictures move when the user taps a forward or backward button), and it is made with a Collection View.  I had to create a custom collection cell view class, which I finished, but now I'm getting an error message in the iOS Simulator, **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** even though my code builds successfully.  The error is in the `ibCollectionView.dataSource = self` line, and because I'm new to Swift and OOP (I learned about a month ago for the first time), I am confused by this error message, especially because there are no `?` operators.  I have included the problem part of my code (the part Xcode showed with the error message) below.  Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class FluidIntakeMainMenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

//MARK: - Collection View Properties
@IBOutlet weak var ibCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var ibCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!


var cellArray:[customCollectionViewCell] = Array(repeatElement(customCollectionViewCell(), count: 6))

let displayedCellDimensions = CGSize(width: 343, height: 248)



//MARK: - Xcode-generated Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    ibCollectionView.dataSource = self
    ibCollectionView.delegate = self


}
//My code for this class continues down here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First and most important thing is to check the IBOutlet connection
>   that you made in your storyboard.

Try to remove the connection in storyboard and then reconnect it.

**Secondly put a debugger on to check if it's still nil.**

```
 ibCollectionView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: How do I put a debugger on? When I've debugged before, I've just read through the lines of code.

Comment: https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/xcode-debugging-with-breakpoints-for-beginners-5b0d0a39d711 

Link should help you but before this try to remove and rename the outlet connection for UICollectionView again from the storyboard.

Comment: The debugger says that my outlets are both nil and the other vars that I clearly initiated have 0 values.  Did I initiate them incorrectly?

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast there is a problem with the outlet you are making.  follow this link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Also do check that the view controller you are making in storyboard has the  custom class set as FluidIntakeMainMenuViewController and then make new outlet connections

Comment: Coincidentally, I went through that tutorial before I started this app.  I'll go through it again, but is it possible that the problem is that I typed the ibCollectionViewLayout outlet into the code rather than command-drag?

Comment: No thats not possible outlets are made using drag drop only. I mean thats the whole point of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151412/discussion-between-programmingenthusiast-and-umar-farooque).

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot about this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Register cell classes
        ibCollectionView?.register(YourCustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

And use "Cell" identifier in cellForItemAt...

Comment: That just gave me the same error in a different spot.  [Here is the rest of my code for that class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463354/why-wont-my-collection-view-cells-display-in-the-iphone-simulator)