# How to exterminate the bug causing this Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, uicollectionviewcell, exc-bad-access

I'm fairly new to Swift (I learned it about a month ago), and I am creating a custom collection view cell, and I am connecting my custom class to the View Controller class.  I am asking this question because I have been struggling with getting a bug

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let answer = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: cellArray.count)

        return answer
}
```

out for several hours.  This bug is a method in my View Controller class, and it displays an error message in the LLDB window "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2...[computer memory address here]" is highlighted at `let answer = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: cellArray.count)` I have [followed this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544) and yet the bug is not exterminated.

I have included the part of my View Controller class where I initialize the properties, if that is helpful:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ibCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var cellArray:[customCollectionViewCell] = Array(repeatElement(customCollectionViewCell(), count: 6))

let displayedCellDimensions = CGSize(width: 343, height: 248)
```

Screenshot of the LLDB interface:
[image: Here is a screenshot of the LLDB interface.]

Any help is appreciated, because I am very stuck.  Thank you!

Comment: The best to exterminate a bug is pesticide!!... Now, seriously, have you checked that collectionView isn't nil and cellArray isn't nil?

Comment: @Gusman I'm pretty sure.  I have edited the post to include a screenshot of the LLDB interface, which shows the memory locations of collectionView

Comment: Hope nobody blames me to point you to an external resource... Try this method for debug the exception, it will give you more info: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544

Comment: @Gusman I've used that tutorial already.  I can try it again, but I already tried creating zombie objects, and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw it. When you activated the zombies, did the debug gave you any extra info?

Comment: Also, is it possible that collectionView doesn't has as many sections as the item count on cellArray?

Comment: @Gusman I believe I still have the zombies activated, and so, yes it's still giving the error.  Also, in the ibCollectionView, I made 0 cells in the IB attributes inspector because I want each custom cell to occupy the entire Collection View space (I will segue between the cells using UIButtons that are defined in my custom cell class). Basically, it's essentially a manually-operated slideshow.

Comment: If collectionView has 0 sections and you ask to get the number of items of an inexistent section then that can cause the problem.

Comment: @Gusman Okay so I changed the number of cell to 6 in the IB attributes inspector (6 is cellArray.count), but its still giving the same error and now I have a warning "prototype collection view cells must have reuse identifiers" even though elsewhere in the View Controller class I have a method to assign reuse identifiers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151501/discussion-between-programmingenthusiast-and-gusman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that you're calling your numberOfItemsInSection recursively:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let answer = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: cellArray.count)

    return answer
```

Instead, you should just give it what it wants, the number of items:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return cellArray.count
```

Another issue when dealing with collectionViews and tableViews occurs when you rename or delete and re-add an InterfaceBuilder outlet in the swift file without modifying the storyboard outlet.  I've included a screenshot so you can see what I mean:

[image: Storyboard, assistant editor, and connections inspector]

If one of those filled in circles is empty, the connection is broken. To fix this:

1. Open the storyboard and select the collection view in the heirarchy.
2. CTRL+Drag from the heirarchy to the swift file in the assistant editor (opened with the hotkey ALT+CMD+Enter)
3. A dialogue should appear.  Enter the settings for the outlet.
4. Clean up any old outlets and broken connections in the swift file and the connections editor.

Comment: Thank you!  I did those things, and now when I go to run the app in iOS Simulator, the app just freezes; the LLDB doesn't display anything; I have to stop the simulation in Xcode.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: Thank you!  I saw that tutorial, but I was told that for this part of the app I didn't need a UICollectionViewController.  [Here is the link to the rest of my code for that class as it is currently.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463354/why-wont-my-collection-view-cells-display-in-the-iphone-simulator).  I inserted a breakpoint at `return cellArray.count` and now it has a green message "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1"  When it runs without a breakpoint, AppDelegate.swift has a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error, which I've gotten before but I'm still not sure what to do here.

Comment: I have been playing with the code all day, and it is still throwing the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.  [Here is my code](https://gist.github.com/ProgrammingExterminator/aebfb74a405200970297002c33d910c1).  I am very lost at this point.